# $(\Bbb N, d)$ and $(\Bbb N, \delta)$ are homeomorphic.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $\Bbb N \subset \Bbb R$ be given the induced euclidean metric $d$ and we consider $\Bbb N$ with the discrete metric $\delta$. To show: $(\Bbb N, d)$ and $(\Bbb N, \delta)$ are homeomorphic.

I think the identity map will play the role of homeomorphism between $(\Bbb N, d)$ and $(\Bbb N, \delta)$ but facing difficulty to prove it. Please Help!!

Comment: Hint: What are the open sets look like in these topologies?

Comment: singleton sets!

Comment: Indeed, all subsets all open.

Comment: You can prove that $id: \mathbb{N},d\to \mathbb{N},\delta$ is a homeomorphism. It is bijective, and the singleton sets form a basis for each.